# Simple way to get issuers and subjects of a cert file

Tags: linux, certificate, ssl-certificate, aws-acm

Got the cert from a domain in my AWS account, the cert is issued by AWS ACM:

```
aws acm get-certificate --certificate-arn  arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:...:certificate/... --query CertificateChain |  jq . -r > ca.pem
```

There are 3 items in that file. I would like to get the issuer and subject for each item in that file. I found the following on the web, and it works ok:

```
$ openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile ca.pem | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -noout
subject=C = US, O = Amazon, OU = Server CA 1B, CN = Amazon

issuer=C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1


subject=C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1

issuer=C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", CN = Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2


subject=C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", CN = Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2

issuer=C = US, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", OU = Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority
```

But, seriously? There is no way to remember this unless you work with that stuff every day. Surely there is something simpler? Another command available on Ubuntu, or maybe a library in Python or Go, or something? anything to make basic cert management simpler than openssl would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a free online tool that purports to perform the function you require. Be sure never to paste a secret key into a public website as this.

https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html

Comment: While this web-based tool "gets the job done" it is inadvisable to paste a secret key into an online web tool. There is legitimate risk of exposure to credential harvesting attack.

Comment: @CharneyKaye important point you make but luckily here, it is the public portion that would be submitted (because it is the chain of trust)

Comment: Good point. Worth adding to the original answer.